# Javascript set left style doesn't work

Tags: javascript, styles

```
xpos=xpos+1;
document.getElementById("img").style.left=xpos;
```

I can't assign xpos value to left property in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a unit to it. Otherwise it's probably not being read by the browser due to it being invalid CSS

```
document.getElementById("img").style.left= xpos + "px";
```

You can usually figure out these kind of things by looking at the styles pane of your browser's developer tools

Comment: No problem. Glad you figured it out :)